# Django Paypal: How To Pass User ID With Webhooks Or In Subscription

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I am trying to pass the user id with the webhook or the subscription so that i can know which user has subscribed. I have seen Stripe do this and the ipn methods for paypal do it so is there a way to do this by their REST API? Is there a better way to do this? i have seen a few hack ways of doing it but they don't seem like the best way.

I am trying to look for ways so i think i can maybe pass the subscriber id by javascript on approve of the subscription and then use that to identify the user but i would rather not use ways that can be manipulated by javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `createSubscription` [API request](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/subscriptions/v1/#subscriptions-create-request-body) or JS payload, add a `custom_id`.  It will be returned in any future [webhook events](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions) you have subscribed to for that client id.

Comment: is there a way to add a `custom_id` to the smart button way?

Comment: In the createSubscription JS payload

Comment: If I need to pass both the id of the product being bought and the user id, do I have any better way than concatenating them both into `custom_id`?

Comment: For subscriptions, it's much more normal to record what "products" or "services" a user has access to at the user or order record level, so only one piece of information needs to be in the ID.  But if you really needed to include multiple values in custom_id (not recommended), you could use `json.dumps` and `json.loads` to form and parse a string from a dict